# Unable to Return JSON Data from NestJS API

Tags: typescript, nestjs, bing-api

I am building a NestJS API which will call Bing's Custom Search Engine endpoint and return the search results in JSON format.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/call-endpoint-nodejs

I am successfully able to call the endpoint using my API key and print the resulting JSON to my console. The issue I have is that the function returns the empty data before the request has a chance to populate the array with any data.

I apologize if the code format is completely wrong or if the entire thing is setup incorrectly. I've never programmed an API before and have to learn it on the fly.

**Controller**

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SearchEngineService } from './search-engine.service';

@Controller('tasks') 
export class SearchEngineController {
    constructor(private searchEngineService: SearchEngineService) {}

    @Get()
    processRequest() {
        return this.searchEngineService.processRequest();
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class SearchEngineService {
    processRequest() {
        var request = require("request"); 
        var searchResponse;
        var webPage;
        var parsedSearchResponse = [];
        var subscriptionKey = "SUBSCRIPTION_KEY";
        var customConfigId = "CONFIG_ID";
        var searchTerm = "partner";

        var info = {
            url: 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bingcustomsearch/v7.0/search?' 
                + 'q=' 
                + searchTerm 
                + "&" 
                + 'customconfig=' 
                + customConfigId,
            headers: {
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey
            }
        }

        request(info, function(error, response, body) {
            searchResponse = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log("\n");
            for (var i = 0; i < searchResponse.webPages.value.length; ++i) {
                webPage = searchResponse.webPages.value[i];
                parsedSearchResponse.push(searchResponse.webPages.value[i]);
            
                console.log('name: ' + parsedSearchResponse[i].name);
                console.log('url: ' + parsedSearchResponse[i].url);
                console.log('displayUrl: ' + parsedSearchResponse[i].displayUrl); 
                console.log('snippet: ' + parsedSearchResponse[i].snippet);
                console.log('dateLastCrawled: ' + parsedSearchResponse[i].dateLastCrawled);
                console.log();
            
            }
            console.log("\n###################################");
        });

        return parsedSearchResponse;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of async programming.

Your function return before the request is finished. As a snippet is worth a thousands words, take a look at what's happening and in which order:

```
// 1. Start an http request and register a callback to back when complete
request(info, function(error, response, body) {
    // 3. This function is called once the request is complete
    searchResponse = JSON.parse(body);

    for (var i = 0; i < searchResponse.webPages.value.length; ++i) {
        webPage = searchResponse.webPages.value[i];
        parsedSearchResponse.push(searchResponse.webPages.value[i]);
    }

    // 4. Your array is ready but your function returned long ago
});

// 2. Return parsedSearchResponse, an empty array at this point
return parsedSearchResponse;
```

You need to wait for your request to finish before returning your function. Best way to do this is via promises. I usually don't recommend to swith to new libraries but as request is deprecated and doesn't support promise I will do an exception and advise you to swith to another http client. I like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) but any client that support promises will do.

Here is a possible solution for your problem, I didn't test it as I don't have credentials but feel free to comment if something is not working.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import axios from 'axios';

// Put this values in environment variable
const subscriptionKey = "SUBSCRIPTION_KEY";
const customConfigId = "CONFIG_ID";

@Injectable()
export class SearchEngineService {
  async processRequest() {
    let webPage;
    const parsedSearchResponse = [];
    const searchTerm = "partner";

    const url = `https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bingcustomsearch/v7.0/search?q=${searchTerm}&customconfig=${customConfigId}`

    const options = {
      headers: {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey
      }
    }

    try {
      const { data: searchResponse } = await axios.get(url, options);

      for (let i = 0; i < searchResponse.webPages.value.length; ++i) {
        webPage = searchResponse.webPages.value[i];
        parsedSearchResponse.push(searchResponse.webPages.value[i]);
      }
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle your error cases
    }

    return parsedSearchResponse;
  }
}
```